# Как доработать ф-цию разделителя текста построково

Tags: python

Всем привет. Не могу доработать функцию которая будет разделять текст на предложения и показывать предложения с новой строки ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ЗАВЕРШАЯ ТОЧКОЙ и что бы последнее предложение было с ОДНОЙ точкой.
Вот мой код

```
def separator(argument):
    return '\n'.join(argument.split('. '))

print(separator('hhhd jsdhfhsd sdjhsdjkf. hfd djss sjhdkjhs sdf. kjsdhfkdsfdfs. dhf  h s djhhkj.'))
```

Должно получиться

```
hhhd jsdhfhsd sdjhsdjkf.
hfd djss sjhdkjhs sdf.
kjsdhfkdsfdfs.
dhf  h s djhhkj.
```

Comment: `return '.\n'.join(argument.split('. '))` . когда вы делаете сплит, символ, по которому проводится разделение, изымается из строки. поэтому его нужно просто добавить в join.

Comment: спасибо огроменное, а всего лишь дело было в одной точке))

Comment: "НОМЕР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ" не в обрабатываемый текст добавляйте, а после обработки. Разбиваете на отдельные строки, и в каждую строку добавляете этот текст. Но вообще это уже другой вопрос, лучше задать его отдельно.

Comment: @insolor что то не пойму

Comment: 1 - задайте отдельный вопрос вместо дополнения этого вопроса. 2 - "номер предложения" нужно добавлять не к параметру функции separator, а результат функции separator разбить на отдельные строки, и к каждой добавить "номер предложения"

Answer (score 0):

```
def separator(argument):
  a = argument.split(".")
  value = ".\n".join(a)
  return value

print(separator('hhhd jsdhfhsd sdjhsdjkf. hfd djss sjhdkjhs sdf. kjsdhfkdsfdfs. dhf  h s djhhkj.'))
```